# Android Unit Test of Kotlin class fails with "cannot find symbol class ..."

Tags: android, gradle, android-testing, kotlin

I've recently added the Kotlin plugin to my Android application's build and now I want to test a Kotlin class in an InstrumentationTestCase.

IntelliJ/Android Studio sees the class in the editor and it seems the class is compiled when launching the app but when I launch `gradlew assembleTest` it fails with "cannot find symbol [name of class]".

In my build.gradle I added the kotlin folder as srcDir

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
}
```

Any advice?

**Edit**: The issue was a conflict between the Kotlin and Retrolambda plugin and is now resolved.

Comment: Can you update the question with a note about your resolution, you said " it seems the issue was an older version of the gradle-retrolambda plugin I am using" in another comment but people shouldn't have to read all comments to know the state of the issue; since it isn't part of an answer either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm from Project Kotlin. Could you answer a few questions to help me reproduce your problem?
Do you run `gradlew assembleTest` from IDE or from commandline? Do you have kotlin-stdlib in dependencies?

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Could you provide us your project? I've created an issue in your tracker, so it'll be great to see your answers here http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-6015

Comment: Natalia, thank you for answering. I've provided some more info over at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/LvlkgNlTvtA where I have also pointed out a workaround. My project is rather big, so I will try to get a minimal working example and post it here and on the bug tracker.

Comment: To answer the other question, yes I have the std-lib in dependencies.

Comment: Oh well, it seems the issue was an older version of the gradle-retrolambda plugin I am using for compatibility reasons. Sorry for the hassle.

Comment: I'm having the same problem (and I don't use gradle-retrolambda). I do have stdlib in dependencies. Kotlin code as such builds, works (I mean the app runs), I only can't run an `InstrumentationCase` based test suite. I'm using Android Studio to run my unit tests.

Comment: To be precise, I'm getting a `NoClassDefFoundError` exception. I can provide my project to you if you're interested - it's just hobby code, I'm interested in Kotlin so I'm trying it out. But not being able to do unit tests would be a showstopper, unfortunately...

Comment: @KonradMorawski the comment section is not a help forum, try YouTrack, the Kotlin community forums, or Kotlin Slack.  You'll find links at http://kotlinlang.org

Answer (score 0):

While the issue is being investigated in the other answer, here's a temporary workaround. Add this to your build.gradle:

```
afterEvaluate { project ->
    project.tasks.findAll {
        it.name.startsWith('compile') && it.name.endsWith('DebugTestJava')
    }.each { Task task ->
        task.dependsOn copyKotlinToTest
    }
}

task copyKotlinToTest(type: Copy) {
    from new File(buildDir, 'tmp/kotlin-classes/debug')
    into new File(buildDir, 'tmp/kotlin-classes/debugTest')
}
```

If you have build variants, you'll need to adjust the names of the folders.

Comment: Doesn't help, unfortunately.